# Compare the last 2 strings of the name of the label to the first 2 string of the variable

Tags: vb.net, loops, label

I have 20 labels with names like `lbl_A1`, `lbl_A2`, `lbl_A3`, `lbl_A4`, `lbl_B1`, `lbl_B2`, `lbl_B3`, `lbl_B4`... until `lbl_E4`. Each labels forecolor should change according to the value in the database, `0 = red, 1 = yellow, 2 = green`.

```
'I arrayed all the values of it, each item contains its specific value
Dim lightFunctions = New Integer() {a1_LightFunction, b1_LightFunction, c1_LightFunction, d1_LightFunction, e1_LightFunction _
           , a2_LightFunction, b2_LightFunction, c2_LightFunction, d2_LightFunction, e2_LightFunction _
           , a3_LightFunction, b3_LightFunction, c3_LightFunction, d3_LightFunction, e3_LightFunction _
           , a4_LightFunction, b4_LightFunction, c4_LightFunction, d4_LightFunction, e4_LightFunction}

    'Loop through each item of array and get the value
    For Each lightFunctionsValue As Integer In lightFunctions

        'Loop through each label in my form
        For Each c As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
            'This is my problem, I don't know how to make this that if it detects that for example the label's name ends with A1 then it should get the value of a1_LightFunction the if it is 0 it should be red
            If c.Name.EndsWith("") and lightFunctionsValue = 0 Then c.ForeColor = color.red
            If c.Name.EndsWith("") and lightFunctionsValue = 1 Then c.ForeColor = color.yellow
            If c.Name.EndsWith("") and lightFunctionsValue = 2 Then c.ForeColor = color.green
        Next
    Next
```

I believed that if I do it like that I can avoid so many if's condition like this

```
    If a1_LightFunction = 0 Then
        lbl_A1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If b1_LightFunction = 0 Then
        lbl_B1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If c1_LightFunction = 0 Then
        lbl_C1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If d1_LightFunction = 0 Then
        lbl_D1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If e1_LightFunction = 0 Then
        lbl_E1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If

    And so on and so forth until it reaches ....

    If e4_LightFunction = 2 Then
        lbl_E4.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
```

Comment: Why dont you write a small class to link a label to a value.  When you change the value for an object  let it set the color.

Comment: Sorry, this may seem a basic question. Does creating a `small class to link a label to a value` means that I dont need to drag and drop 20 labels to the GUI?

Comment: @Plutonix your answer has been deleted sir, i'm still in the middle of trying it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you may need is a little abstraction and a way to link labels with some sort of key:

```
Private lblCol As Dictionary(Of String, Label)
...
Dim lbls As Label() = {Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5}
Dim keys As String() = {"lbl_a1", "lbl_c1", "lbl_b4", "lbl_d3"}

lblCol = New Dictionary(Of String, Label)
For n As Int32 = 0 To keys.Count - 1
    lblCol.Add(keys(n), lbls(n))
Next
```

Then a generic updater:

```
Private Sub UpdateLabel(lbl As Label, n As Int32)
    Select Case n
        Case 0
            lbl.BackColor = Color.Red
        Case 1
            lbl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Case 2
            lbl.BackColor = Color.Green
    End Select
End Sub
```

Loop thru all of them:

```
For Each kvp In lblCol
    UpdateLabel(kvp.Value, RNG.Next(0, 3))
Next
```

To find them use the key, which in your original method was the name:

```
Dim find = "lbl_a1"
UpdateLabel(lblCol(find), RNG.Next(0, 3))
```

The key needs to be something simple from the DB to allow you to set up the link/map and make it simple to find the right control.

`RNG` is a `Random` object, you would use the DB values.

Comment: Thank you  so much, never though that the dictionary is the *key* here.